# Disabling Friendly URL doesn't work and getting 404 (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I want to disable the automatic friendly URL browsing in visual studio when I load a page.

Most of the answers that I've read say that I should comment out the following line in RouteConfig.cs.

```
 routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

I did this when I load the page (browse with) in Visual Studio 2013, it still loads it as Friendly URL and throws 404 error. I am running a web form project in C#. Using IIS Express within Visual Studio to run the site.

How can I disable the friendly URL so it will load my browser.aspx page correctly?

Comment: After commenting the line out, make an HTTP request to `browser.aspx`. Watch the network traffic. Does it send an HTTP redirect?

Comment: @mason yes, 301 redirect

Comment: @mason The problem was that the 301 redirection was cached. After deleting the cache it worked. You can write an answer and I'll accept because you lead me to the solution.

Comment: Nah I'll pass, go ahead and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the 301 redirection was cached. After deleting the cache it worked. (thanks to mason for providing a hint to check the network traffic).